# box2dlight libgdx point light not working

Tags: java, libgdx, box2dlights

So I making a 2d game using the libgdx library. Recently I have been trying to incorporate a lighting system into the game using box2dlights library. However, for some reason the point light wont appear on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private ShapeRenderer sr;
private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;

    private RayHandler rayHandler;
    private World world;

    private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

private float animationTime = 0;
private Player player;
private int X = 400;
private int currentDirection = 0;
private int bulletDirection = 0;
private boolean animationPlaying = true;
private boolean animationPlaying2 = true;
public Animation walking;
public Animation walkingLeft;
public Animation walkingRight;
public Animation walkingUp;

private CollisionObjects CO;
private ArrayList<playerPositions> allPlayers = new ArrayList<playerPositions>();

//modes
ArrayList<BulletWorks> bullets = new ArrayList<BulletWorks>();
public boolean leftMode = false;
public boolean frontMode = true;
public boolean rightMode = false;
public boolean upMode = false;
public ArrayList<positions> pos = new ArrayList<positions>();
public float zoom = 0.1f;
public float xposCamera = 0f;
public float yposCamera = 0f;
boolean keyProcessed = true;
boolean play = false;
private float currentPosx = 400;
private float currentPosy = 400;

private PointLight pt;

    public gameFirst(GameTrial game) {
        TmxMapLoader loader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = loader.load("data/WhiteWater.tmx");
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        sr = new ShapeRenderer();

            camera = new OrthographicCamera();
            world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);

            rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
            rayHandler.setCulling(true);
            rayHandler.useDiffuseLight(true);
            rayHandler.setAmbientLight(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f,1.0f);



        player = new Player("prithvi2502", "currymonster69");
        CO = new CollisionObjects();
        allPlayers.add(CO.addPositionPlayers(player));

        pt = new PointLight(rayHandler, 50, Color.CYAN, 40, 400, 300);

        camera.zoom = .5f;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Update
        renderer.setView(camera);
            rayHandler.update();

        rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera.combined.cpy().scl(100));

        // Render
        renderer.render();

        batch.begin();
        inputUpdate();
        camera.update();
        characterUpdate();
        batch.end();

        rayHandler.render();
    }

    public void characterUpdate() {
            allPlayers = CO.updatePlayerPositions(player.getPlayerID(), player.getPlayerCurrentPosX(), player.getPlayerCurrentPosY(), allPlayers);
        currentPosx =  player.getPlayerCurrentPosX();
    currentPosy = player.getPlayerCurrentPosY();
        for(int i=0; i < allPlayers.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(allPlayers.get(i).getPlayerID() + " " + allPlayers.get(i).getX() + " " + allPlayers.get(i).getY());
            currentPosx = allPlayers.get(i).getX();
            currentPosy = allPlayers.get(i).getY();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
            if(bullets.get(i).getDirection() == 0) {
                    bullets.get(i).updateButtom();
                            if(bullets.get(i).didCollide(allPlayers) == true) {
                                    System.out.println("HIT");
                                    bullets.remove(i);
                            } else if(bullets.get(i).getY() > 0 && bullets.get(i).getY() < 1080) {
                                    bullets.get(i).draw(batch);
                            }else {
                                    bullets.remove(i);
                            }
            } else if(bullets.get(i).getDirection() == 1) {
                    bullets.get(i).updateLeft();
                            if(bullets.get(i).didCollide(allPlayers) == true) {
                                    System.out.println("HIT");
                                    bullets.remove(i);
                            } else if(bullets.get(i).getX() > 0 && bullets.get(i).getX() < 1920) {
                                    bullets.get(i).draw(batch);
                            } else {
                                    bullets.remove(i);
                            }
            } else if(bullets.get(i).getDirection() == 2) {
                    bullets.get(i).updateRight();
                            if(bullets.get(i).didCollide(allPlayers) == true) {
                                    System.out.println("HIT");
                                    bullets.remove(i);
                            } else if(bullets.get(i).getX() > 0 && bullets.get(i).getX() < 1920) {
                                    bullets.get(i).draw(batch);
                            } else {
                                    bullets.remove(i);
                            }
            } else if(bullets.get(i).getDirection() == 3) {
                    bullets.get(i).updateTop();
                            if(bullets.get(i).didCollide(allPlayers) == true) {
                                    System.out.println("HIT");
                                    bullets.remove(i);
                            } else if(bullets.get(i).getY() > 0 && bullets.get(i).getY() < 1080) {
                                    bullets.get(i).draw(batch);
                            } else {
                                    bullets.remove(i);
                            }
            }

        }
    }
    public void inputUpdate() {
            if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A) ){
           player.moveLeft(camera, batch);
           currentDirection = 2;
        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D) ){
            player.moveRight(camera, batch);
            currentDirection = 1;
        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S) ){
            player.moveDown(camera, batch);
            currentDirection = 0;
        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W) ){
            player.moveUp(camera, batch);
            currentDirection = 3;
        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.T) ){
            BulletWorks BW = new BulletWorks((1920/2) + 300, 1080/2, (int) currentPosx, (int) currentPosy);
            bulletDirection = 2;
            BW.setDirection(bulletDirection);
                bullets.add(BW);

        }else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)){
            BulletWorks BW = new BulletWorks(1920/2, 1080/2, (int) currentPosx, (int) currentPosy);

                player.shoot(camera, batch);
                if(currentDirection == 0){
                    bulletDirection = 0;

            }else if(currentDirection == 1){
                    bulletDirection = 1;

            }else if(currentDirection == 2){
                    bulletDirection = 2;

            }else if(currentDirection == 3){
                    bulletDirection = 3;

            }
                BW.setDirection(bulletDirection);
                bullets.add(BW);
        }else{

            if(player.frontMode){
                    setGameToNormal(player.getTexture());

            }else if(player.rightMode){
                    setGameToNormal(player.getTexture3());

            }else if(player.leftMode){
                    setGameToNormal(player.getTexture2());

            }else if(player.upMode){
                    setGameToNormal(player.getTexture4());

            }
                play = false;
        }
    }
    private void setGameToNormal(TextureRegion texture) {
            batch.draw(texture, 1920/2, 1080/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
            camera.setToOrtho(false, 1920, 1080);
    }



    @Override
    public void hide() {


    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {


    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {


    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
            rayHandler.dispose();
            world.dispose();
            renderer.dispose();
            map.dispose();
            batch.dispose();
            textureAtlas.dispose();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to render your lights on the default (black) background that is created every time libgdx refreshes your screen. The black background overweights and the lights cannot be rendered properly. Black 'swallows' the light.

I had the same problem when i first tried out Box2D-lights. I solved it by rendering a colored background through a 1x1 pixel texture over the whole screen before calling *rayHandler.render();*

Example code:

```
private SpriteBatch batch;
private World world;
private RayHandler rayHandler;
private Texture texture;
private OrthographicCamera camera;

@Override
public void show(){
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 50, 50/16*9);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    camera.update();
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
    texture = new Texture("white.png"); // 1x1 pixel texture
    rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
    new PointLight(rayHandler, 32, Color.CYAN, 20, 0, 0);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    world.step(delta, 8, 3);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, -Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, -Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.end();
    
    rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera.combined);
    rayHandler.updateAndRender();
}
```

Running this code, i get the following [result](http://postimg.org/image/imxzcg85h/)

I am not quite sure if this is the best way to do it, but it worked for me :)

Comment: So exactly how would I go about doing this. Thanks. sorry i am a newbee to libgdx

Answer (score 0):

Set rayHandler.setAmbientLight(1);
It is set at default to 0 which may be the problem.It solved the same issue for me!